# how to send one directory using Socket in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make an application which sends a directory which contains a tree of files/directories from one computer to another one.

I've searched but I couldn't find much. Is there any ready function?

How do I to proceed with this please?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT:

1. **OS:** Windows 7 SP1.
2. **IDE**: VS2013.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows' own Explorer can do that, via FTP or web connect or whatever.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, can you please detail more?

Comment: with Explorer you can just drag and drop folders. i suggest you try that with files first. you can try pasting `ftp://rtfm.mit.edu/` into the address bar (not sure if that old FTP site is still running, I can't test it reliably because this connection is strangled).

Comment: Do you want to just send the file and folder names, or the contents of the files as well?

Comment: Start reading documentation and researching, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using FTP can be a good method.

[WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html) have function relative FTP.

Many developers have been recommanding using libcurl rather than using WinInet. 
However, it depends complexity and scale of your application.

Comment: it's better to use `libcurl`

Answer (score 0):

The by far easiest would be to use a network share resp. share a directory on the target computer. That would work with *nix systems as well, using Samba. If that's possible the operation boils down to simple file system copies. If that's not possible:

I think you must create an archive of the directory tree before you can send it through a network connection. You could call that serializing. .NET 4.5 has built-in support for creating zip files, cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

How to traverse a dorectory tree is shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

How to use FTP programmatically is shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. But you'll need a running FTP server on the remote machine.

The remaining problem is how to unzip the file at the destination. For that you'll need a logon.